# How to mock out a signed transaction w/ Waffle Mocks?

Tags: contract-development, hardhat, test, waffle, mock

When applying Waffle mock to simulate a contract method that must be explicity signed an error is thrown:

```
Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from (operation="overrides.from", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.1.1)
```

This is the test code:

```
  const provider = waffle.provider;
  [senderMock] = provider.getWallets();
  lockedToken = await deployMockContract(senderMock, LockedToken.abi);
  await lockedToken.mock.addAdmin.returns();
  ...
  await lockedToken.addAdmin(escrow.address, { from: multisig });
```

Same code but default signing it works Ok:

```
  ...
  await lockedToken.addAdmin(escrow.address);
```

So, is not Waffle mock working w/ explicity signed calls? Or is there any workaround? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Per https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2000, you can do:

`await lockedToken.connect(multisig).addAdmin(escrow.address);`